# tensorflow padded_batch analogue of np.pad('edge')

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a batch of tensors `X` with individual shapes `x[t_i][j]` where `t_i` is the sequence length of batch element `i`, I would like to use `padded_batch` to pad the tensors to `t_max` length such that `x[t_i <= t < t_max] = x[t_i]`.

Not using `padded_batch`, I would simply do

```
batch_x = ... #list of tensors to padded_batch
t_max = ... #longest sequence length of batch

new_batch = []
for x in batch_x:
    row = tf.expand_dims(x[-1],axis=0)
    rows = tf.tile(row,[t_max-x.shape[0],1])
    padded_x = tf.concat([x,rows],axis=0]
    new_batch.append(padded_x)
return tf.stack(new_batch,axis=0)
```

It doesn't seem like there is enough control using the agruments of `padded_batch`.

The only thing I can think of is to keep each feature tensor separate for batch_padding.  Then concatenating the batched_padded features.

edit:
I realized that this is the numpy equivalent of `np.pad(x,(0,pad_len),'edge')`